# Download itab technical field names into Excel

Tags: excel, dynamic, abap

I need a process to download the fields of a table (technical names, field names) and first 5 rows.

In below code I am able to download everything except from technical fieldnames, how to extend it?

I get field names and their values but I also need the second row of the excel, i.e. technical names of the fields (MATNR, MATKL, etc).

Thank you in advance.

```
DATA: v_default_file_name TYPE string,
      v_filename          TYPE string,
      v_file_path         TYPE string,
      wa_table            TYPE dd02l,
      check_path          TYPE string,
      v_select            TYPE string,
      t_fieldcat          TYPE lvc_t_fcat,
      v_xml_version       TYPE string,
      v_xml_flavour       TYPE string,
      v_xstring           TYPE xstring,
      v_size              TYPE i,
      gt_bintab           TYPE solix_tab.

DATA: r_data        TYPE REF TO data,
      r_structdescr TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr,
      r_table       TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table,
      r_columns     TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns_table,
      r_aggreg      TYPE REF TO cl_salv_aggregations,
      r_result_data TYPE REF TO cl_salv_ex_result_data_table.

FIELD-SYMBOLS: <table> TYPE ANY TABLE,
               <fs_component> TYPE abap_compdescr.

PARAMETERS: p_table TYPE dd02l-tabname .
PARAMETERS: p_path  TYPE string        OBLIGATORY.

INITIALIZATION.
  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-name = P_PATH.
      screen-input = 0.
      MODIFY SCREEN.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON VALUE-REQUEST FOR p_path.
  CONCATENATE p_table 'EXCEL_' SY-DATUM INTO v_default_file_name.
  cl_gui_frontend_services=>file_save_dialog(
    EXPORTING
      window_title        = ''
      default_extension   = 'XLS'
      default_file_name   = v_default_file_name
      initial_directory   = 'Desktop'
      prompt_on_overwrite = 'X'
    CHANGING
      filename            = v_filename
      path                = v_file_path
      fullpath            = p_path ).

  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
   MESSAGE 'ERROR' TYPE 'E'.
   EXIT.
  ENDIF.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  TRANSLATE v_file_path TO UPPER CASE.
  CONCATENATE v_file_path v_default_file_name '.XLS' INTO check_path.

  SELECT SINGLE tabname  INTO wa_table FROM dd02l
          WHERE tabname  EQ   p_table
            AND tabclass EQ   'TRANSP'.

  IF sy-subrc NE 0.
    MESSAGE 'ERROR' TYPE 'E'.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.

  IF p_path EQ check_path.
*   Select all data
    PERFORM get_table_data.
*   Build excel output data
    PERFORM build_excel_data.
*   Export excel file
    PERFORM export_excel.
  ELSE.
    MESSAGE 'ERROR' TYPE 'E'.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.

FORM get_table_data.
  CREATE DATA r_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF (p_table).
  ASSIGN r_data->* TO <table>.
* Get all columns for select
 r_structdescr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_name( p_table ).
  IF r_structdescr IS BOUND.
    LOOP AT r_structdescr->components[] ASSIGNING <fs_component>.
    CONCATENATE v_select <fs_component>-name INTO v_select SEPARATED BY space.
   ENDLOOP.
  ENDIF.
* Select all data
  SELECT (v_select) FROM (p_table) INTO TABLE <table>
      UP TO 2 ROWS.
ENDFORM.                   "get_table_data

FORM build_excel_data.
  TRY.
      cl_salv_table=>factory(
      EXPORTING
        list_display = abap_false
      IMPORTING
        r_salv_table = r_table
      CHANGING
        t_table     = <table> ).
    CATCH cx_salv_msg.
  ENDTRY.

* Get columns and aggregation to create fieldcatalog
  r_columns  = r_table->get_columns( ).
  r_aggreg   = r_table->get_aggregations( ).
  t_fieldcat = cl_salv_controller_metadata=>get_lvc_fieldcatalog(
                                r_columns     = r_columns
                                r_aggregations = r_aggreg ).

* Create result data table
  IF cl_salv_bs_a_xml_base=>get_version( ) EQ if_salv_bs_xml=>version_25 OR
     cl_salv_bs_a_xml_base=>get_version( ) EQ if_salv_bs_xml=>version_26.
    r_result_data = cl_salv_ex_util=>factory_result_data_table(
        r_data                     = r_data
        t_fieldcatalog             = t_fieldcat ).

* Get XML version
    CASE cl_salv_bs_a_xml_base=>get_version( ).
      WHEN if_salv_bs_xml=>version_25.
        v_xml_version = if_salv_bs_xml=>version_25.
      WHEN if_salv_bs_xml=>version_26.
        v_xml_version = if_salv_bs_xml=>version_26.
    ENDCASE.

* Get XML flavour
    v_xml_flavour = if_salv_bs_c_tt=>c_tt_xml_flavour_export.

* Create excel data
    CALL METHOD cl_salv_bs_tt_util=>if_salv_bs_tt_util~transform(
      EXPORTING
        xml_type     = if_salv_bs_xml=>c_type_mhtml
        xml_version  = v_xml_version
        r_result_data = r_result_data
        xml_flavour  = v_xml_flavour
        gui_type     = if_salv_bs_xml=>c_gui_type_gui
      IMPORTING
        xml          = v_xstring ).
   ENDIF.
  ENDFORM.                    "build_excel_data

  FORM export_excel.
   IF v_xstring IS NOT INITIAL.
    CALL FUNCTION 'SCMS_XSTRING_TO_BINARY'
      EXPORTING
        buffer       = v_xstring
      IMPORTING
        output_length = v_size
      TABLES
        binary_tab   = gt_bintab.

    CALL METHOD cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_download(
      EXPORTING
        bin_filesize           = v_size
        filename               = p_path
        filetype               = 'BIN'
      CHANGING
        data_tab               = gt_bintab ).
  ENDIF.
ENDFORM.                    "export_excel
```

Comment: Please edit your question by reducing your code to the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that to focus on the real problem and so that people can reproduce in their system. No need of top comments, unused variables, exception names, useless comments like "select all data" before `PERFORM get_all_data`, useless blank lines and so on. Focus on one table common to all systems like `T002` (language keys) so that to remove code which checks the existence of the table in `DD02L`. Add an Excel screenshot and show what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive the problem here is the generation of excel through ALV.

Adding a first row with the technical fields is not feasible since the `<table>` field symbol has the mara (for example) structure, and you can't pass string 'MTART' in a char1 type

I think you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

do not use ALV and generate the excel through other means, so that you can handle **string types** in your table. For example you can try function `ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE`

**Option 2**

try passing `R_TOP_OF_LIST` parameter to the method `cl_salv_ex_util=>factory_result_data_table`.

The result will be *near* what you asked, but maybe it can be acceptable: The technical fields will be added before the names and with a blank line between

```
DATA gt_components TYPE abap_compdescr_tab.
DATA lr_content TYPE REF TO cl_salv_form_element.
DATA lr_form TYPE REF TO cl_salv_form.

". . .
gt_components = r_structdescr->components[].
". . .

PERFORM built_header  CHANGING lr_content. " builds the technical names list
create OBJECT lr_form.
lr_form->set_content( lr_content ).

". . .
r_result_data = cl_salv_ex_util=>factory_result_data_table(
    r_data                     = r_data
    t_fieldcatalog             = t_fieldcat
    r_top_of_list              = lr_form

". . .

FORM built_header CHANGING cr_content TYPE REF TO cl_salv_form_element.

  DATA: lr_grid   TYPE REF TO cl_salv_form_layout_grid,
        lr_label  TYPE REF TO cl_salv_form_label.

  CREATE OBJECT lr_grid.

  LOOP AT gt_components into data(ls_comp).
  data(col) = sy-tabix.
  lr_label = lr_grid->create_label(
    row     = 1
    column  = col
    text    = ls_comp-name
    tooltip = '' ).
  ENDLOOP.

  cr_content = lr_grid.
ENDFORM.                    " built_header
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrite your `get_table_data` subroutine like this:

```
FORM get_table_data.
 r_structdescr ?= cl_abap_structdescr=>describe_by_name( p_name ).
 DATA(components) = r_structdescr->get_components( ).
 DATA(fields) = VALUE ddfields( FOR line IN r_structdescr->get_ddic_field_list( ) ( line ) ).
 
 " making all fields string
 MODIFY components FROM VALUE abap_componentdescr( type = CAST #( cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'STRING' ) ) ) TRANSPORTING type WHERE name <> ''.
 
 r_structdescr = cl_abap_structdescr=>create( components ).
 DATA(o_ref_table) = cl_abap_tabledescr=>create( p_line_type = r_structdescr p_table_kind = cl_abap_tabledescr=>tablekind_std ).
 
 CHECK o_ref_table IS BOUND.
 
 CREATE DATA r_data TYPE HANDLE o_ref_table.
 ASSIGN r_data->* TO <fs_table>.
 APPEND INITIAL LINE TO <fs_table>. " reserving line for headers
 
 DATA(select_cols) = REDUCE string( INIT col TYPE char2048 FOR <fld> IN fields NEXT col = COND #(
                     WHEN col <> space THEN col && `, ` && `CAST( ` && <fld>-fieldname && ` AS CHAR( ` && <fld>-leng && ` ) ) AS ` && <fld>-fieldname
                     ELSE `CAST( ` && <fld>-fieldname && ` AS CHAR( ` && <fld>-leng && ` ) ) AS ` && <fld>-fieldname ) ).
 
 SELECT (select_cols)
   UP TO 10 ROWS
   FROM (p_name)
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @<table>.
 
 " writing headers
 ASSIGN <table>[ 1 ] TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<empty>).
 LOOP AT fields ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<field>).
   ASSIGN COMPONENT <field>-fieldname OF STRUCTURE <empty> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<heading>).
   CHECK sy-subrc = 0.
   <heading> = <field>-fieldname.
 ENDLOOP.
ENDFORM.
```